# wpf canvas ManipulationStarted event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

this Q might be wrong because I just started wpf.

on msdn I found that the Canvas has the event ManipulationStarted : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms609101(v=VS.100).aspx

just search on the page for ManipulationStarted.

The problem is in Visual Studion when I try to use the event, it gives an error that says that this does not exists on the canvas element, I can't find it in the event list for canvas either , nor can I find any other events that are related to Manipulation.

I'm using VS 2010 and .net 4

Am I doing something wrong ? Are there more Canvas classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot think of many reasons why that would be, what namespaces do you use? Did you try in XAML or code-behind?

What i suspect is that your project in fact simply is not .NET 4 but something older in which it does not exist, can you confirm that you really use .NET 4?

Comment: thanks! that was it. I downloaded the project from codeproject and didn't checked the .net version.